# Using Standardization in sklearn pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn, normalization, pipeline

I am using Standardscaler to normalize my dataset, that is I turn each feature into a z-score, by subtracting the mean and dividing by the Std.

I would like to use Standardscaler within sklearn's pipeline and I am wondering how exactly the transformation is applied to X_test. That is, in the code below, when I run `pipeline.predict(X_test)`, it is my understanding that the `StandardScaler` and `SVC()` is run on X_test, but what exactly does `Standardscaler` use as the mean and the StD? The ones from the `X_Train` or does it compute those only for `X_test`? What if, for instance `X_test` consists only of 2 variables, the normalization would look a lot different than if I had normalized `X_train` and `X_test` altogether, right?

```
steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler()),
     ('model',SVC())] 
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)
pipeline.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = pipeline.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sklearn's `pipeline` will apply `transformer.fit_transform()` when `pipeline.fit()` is called and `transformer.transform()` when `pipeline.predict()` is called.  So for your case, `StandardScaler` will be fitted to `X_train` and then the *mean* and *stdev* from `X_train` will be used to scale `X_test`.

The transform of `X_train` would indeed look different to that of `X_train` and `X_test`.  The extent of the difference would depend on the extent of the difference in the distributions between `X_train` and `X_test` combined.  However, if randomly partitioned from the same original dataset, and of a reasonable size, the distributions of `X_train` and `X_test` will probably be similar.

Regardless, it is important to treat `X_test` as though it is out of sample, in order for it to be a (hopefully) reliable metric for unseen data.  Since you don't know the distribution of unseen data, you should pretend you don't know the distribution of `X_test`, including the *mean* and *stdev*.

Comment: Very happy to hear that, that makes perfect sense. Thank you so much for the explanation Chris!!

Comment: @Tartaglia glad to be able to help.